# Poisson equation with FFT and normalization

Tags: fourier-analysis, poisson, spectral-method

I'm trying to understand how to solve Poisson equation with FFT. Say, if we have the simplest periodic example 
$$u_{xx}=-4\pi\cos(x)$$

The solution then should be 
$$u=4\pi\cos(x)$$ 
I really get the cosine, but with a different magnitude. So what I`m missing, and how to normalize solution with FFT properly?

My code is following:

```
clear all;
Xmin=-8*pi;
Xmax=8*pi;
Nsteps=800;
h=(Xmax-Xmin)/Nsteps;
x=[Xmin:h:Xmax]+10e-6;
f=-4*pi*cos(x);

F=fft(f);
k=2*pi./x;
FI=-F./k.^2;
fi=real(ifft(FI));

fiReal=4*pi*cos(x);

%%
figure,
subplot(1, 2, 1);
plot(x,fi) ; title('FFT solution')
subplot(1, 2, 2);
plot(x,fiReal); title('Analytical solution')
```

[image]

Comment: You are computing your wavenumbers $k$ wrong. You should not be dividing by $x$.

Comment: @whpowell96, So how to compute them properly? I thought k should be points in reciprocal space. Something like `k=[0:Nsteps].*2*pi/(Xmax-Xmin);` leads to wrong solution.

Comment: the wave number is 2pi/L. I want to know how to compute the first term when k=0. since it is divided by zero?